# How to check if the iterator in the for expression is a val or var?

Tags: scala

I was reading how different for expressions can have a var or val for their generator for expression. How can one determine if the iterator is a var or val?

Comment: An example would be great, because I did not understand anything.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  for(i to fileHere.length-1) I read in a book introduces i as a variable while this example here for(file <- fileHere) introduces a val called file. Is there a way to determine if the iterator is a val or var?

Comment: `var`s and `val`s are both variables. A `var` is a mutable variable and a `val` is an immutable variable. `for(i to fileHere.length-1)` is not valid syntax and does not introduce `i` as a variable.

Answer (score 3):

Symbols introduced by a `for` expression are always `val` and cannot be changed:

```
for (i <- 1 to 10) {
  println(i) // Yes
  i = -1 // No
}
```

A `val` will always refer to the same object, whereas a `var` can be updated to refer to a different object. But in both cases it is possible that the object it refers to can be changed, if it is a mutable object.